# Stop UITableView Animation on push to UINavigationController

Tags: ios

I'm pushing a view controller that contains a tableiview onto my uinavigation controller:

```
CourseMenuViewController *mvc = [[[CourseMenuViewController alloc] initWithSlidingNavigationcontroller:self.slidingNavigationController] autorelease];
mvc.course = course;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

So far so good, everything works as expected.  My issue occurs when I watch the animation and see all of my table view rows animate down from the top of the screen as the view is animating in from the left.  This makes it feel like the view is moving from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner in a diagonal path.

My question is, how can I make the table view just appear instead of animating?  I should add that all of my cells are static so I'm not waiting on any data from a NSFetchedResultsController or anything like that.

roronoa below put me on the right path, and here is the now working version:

```
CourseMenuViewController *mvc = [[[CourseMenuViewController alloc] initWithSlidingNavigationcontroller:self.slidingNavigationController] autorelease];
mvc.course = course;

CATransition *caTransition = [CATransition animation];
caTransition.duration = 0.35;
caTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
caTransition.delegate = self;
caTransition.type = kCATransitionPush;
caTransition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:caTransition forKey:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:NO];
```

Comment: initWithSlidingNavigationcontroller is a custom initiation that u wrote in ur CourseMenuViewController class?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that just consider it a UINavigationController.  I needed some custom functionality but that functionality doesn't affect the standard push logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned details about your class CourseMenuViewController and initWithSlidingNavigationcontroller , but you can use the following to get the job done:-

```
CourseMenuViewController *mvc =[[CourseMenuViewController alloc] init];
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[mvc release];
```

you can have any type of animation that you want in the above code by changing the animation constants according to your need without having unwanted animations on your tableview.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right path.  I've updated my question to include the working version of the code.